# Dnsmasq problem with Linux network namespace

Tags: linux, networking, dnsmasq, network-namespaces

I have tried to use dnsmasq as the name server for virtual machines. On all the vm-s, `/etc/resolv.conf` indicates the vm need to access `192.168.15.3` to resolve the domain names. However, the interface holding 192.168.15.3 is lying inside a network namespace on the host.

I can `ping 192.168.15.3` from both virtual machine and host(inside the network namespace). And `lsof -i:53` outside the network namespace shows dnsmasq is listening on port 53. If I run `lsof -i:53` inside the network namespace, there is nothing.

If I change the content in `/etc/resolv.conf` to use any interface's ip address in host's public namespace, the name resolution works well. It seems that dnsmasq process didn't go wrong.

I've tried `ip netns exec <THE NAMESPACE> systemctl start dnsmasq` after stops dnsmasq, but only see dnsmasq opens its port inside the public namespace.

What should I do if I don't want to modify `resolv.conf` inside the vm but only configure something on the host? How to make port 53 accessible inside the network namespace?

Answer (score 0):

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ip-netns.8.html

> A network namespace is logically another copy of the network stack,
>          with its own routes, firewall rules, and network devices.

So you need something like this:
[Iptables to redirect DNS lookup IP and Port](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/144482/iptables-to-redirect-dns-lookup-ip-and-port)